# Why Internet Explorer loads one image more than one time on some situations?

Tags: php, image, internet-explorer, captcha, limesurvey

I have a simple form with a button. Pressing the button calls GET on a PHP page. On the page there's only an IMG tag, where SRC is a PHP script that returns a PNG image dynamically (`imagepng()` function).

Why does Internet Explorer 9 load this image more than once?

It can be a little tricky to verify that this happening. I discovered this because I was debugging a PHP script (the one that generates the PNG) with PHPEd and realized that the flow entered twice in the file, stoping on my breakpoint twice!

I confirmed this when I looked at the IE's network log and saw that there really was more than one call to the script. To view the Network Log, press F12 on IE window and click the "Network" tab.

According to the log, there is a call that is not fully completed (not returns the HTTP 200 status), but this is sufficient to mess everything.

Any suggestions on how to workaround this?

I've done some example scripts to demonstrate the problem:

File "teste.php"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php 
  $handle = fopen("teste.txt", "w");
  fclose($handle);  
?>
    <img src="verification.php" alt="captcha">
    <form action="teste.php" method="get">
      <input type="submit" value="Go!">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

File "verification.php"

```
<?php
  $im = imagecreatetruecolor(75, 20);
  $black = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
  $red = ImageColorAllocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
  $blue = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
  $grey_shade = ImageColorAllocate($im, 204, 204, 204);

  srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

  $num1 = rand(1,5);

  $found = false;

  while (!$found) {
    $num2 = rand(1,100);

    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $num2/5)) {
      $found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  $font_c_rand = rand(1,3);

  if ($font_c_rand == 1) {
    $font_color = $black;
  } else if ($font_c_rand == 2) {
    $font_color = $red;
  } else if ($font_c_rand == 3) {
    $font_color = $blue;
  }

  $font = "vera.ttf";

  $line_rand = rand(1,3);

  if ($line_rand == 1) {
    $line_color = $black;
  } else if ($line_rand == 2) {
    $line_color = $red;
  } else if ($line_rand == 3) {
    $line_color = $blue;
  }

  ImageFill($im, 0, 0, $grey_shade);
  imageline($im,0,0,0,20,$line_color);
  imageline($im,74,0,74,19,$line_color);
  imageline($im,0,0,74,0,$line_color);
  imageline($im,0,19,74,19,$line_color);
  ImageTTFText($im, 10, 0, 3, 15,$font_color, $font,  $num1." + ".$num2." =" );


  imagepng($im);
  imagedestroy($im);

  $handle = fopen("teste.txt", "a");
  fwrite($handle, "\"verification.php\ executed!". The sum result is " . ($num1 + $num2) ."\n");
  fclose($handle);  
?>
```

As you can see, you will need one ttf font. Put on the same folder the font file and chage the $font variable on the above script. You can use any True Type font, take a look:

> $font = "arial.ttf";

The only requirement is that the ttf file must be on the same folder of the scripts, to turn everything more simple.

To test the correct behaviour:

1. open the file "teste.php" on the Internet Explorer;
2. Press some times the refresh button on the browser;
3. take a look into the file named "teste.txt", created dynamically.

Result: there are only one line on the file. The contents says the correct sum value showed on the captcha image. This is the correct behaviour, because the verification.php is called only one time, on the display of the captcha image.

Now, to test the problem:

1. open the file "teste.php" on the Internet Explorer;
2. Press the "GO!" button on the form some times. 3x is enough;
3. take a look into the file named "teste.txt", created dynamically.

Result: there are more than one line on the file. Probably 2. One of them has the correct answer of the captcha image sum. These two call to create the image is messing the correct answer to the captcha system, and so, there are no way to use it with internet explorer.

How to workaround this for IE? In Firefox everything is OK!

PS.: I'm trying to use the captcha system of the [Lime Survey](http://www.limesurvey.org) PHP Script, but because of the above problem it doesn't work wit IE.

Comment: Why do you ask to press the go button several times? What happens if you only press once?

Comment: @Picarus after do the first test (pressing the refresh button some times) the first time you press the go button always generates the correct behaviour. Only after some presses on the button (2x for example) the things are messed... All my testes were done on IE 9. It is or not a strange error?

Comment: If I understand correctly, pressing the refresh button shouldn't cause the submit...this is strange. Am I missing something? The refresh just loads the pho file, but it is not executed. I am on my iPad and I can't test, sorry.

Comment: @Picarus Yes. The refresh does not cause submit, indeed. But there are no link between the submit action and the problem. I've done a test w/o the form. I added an onClick event handler to the image and on click it: window.location = "teste.php". Doing this the problem occurs the same way, so, there are no direct relation with the form submit and the problem. Please. As soon you can, try to reproduce the test. Its very strange...

Comment: Not every image gets put in the cache.  It's a cache, which means resources may or may not be there when IE looks.

Comment: @jeffamaphone So? How to make IE load the image only one time? This is all the problem...

Comment: You should focus on why the page load executes the submit...this is the real problem. Change your question, maybe.

Comment: Have you looked at the cache headers your webserver is sending in the http response, using Fiddler?

Comment: @Picarus well, I guess the page load DOES NOT executes the submit. Please take a look at my example and the steps to reproduce.

Comment: @jeffamaphone No, I do not know how to use fiddler. Can you explain into a answer? Any help is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Download FiddlerTool and run it, and then load the page.  You'll see the HTTP requests in the list once you've done that.  You can see the request and response headers.  Look for things with the word "cache" in them.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I've done tests with fiddler and I got the following results: calling the verification.php on Internet Explorer directly at addressbar generates two GETs. The first one has the following structure: GET /limesurvey/verification.php?sid=1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: pt-BR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost
Cookie: ls65254926239444871148-runtime-1=is6lt224lt66hdg2d5n5t6tuc7

Comment: @jeffamaphone The second GET has the following structure: GET /limesurvey/verification.php?sid=1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: GbPlugin
Host: localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ls65254926239444871148-runtime-1=is6lt224lt66hdg2d5n5t6tuc7. Can you say something about this IE behaviour?

Comment: I call this BS. I is most likely a problem with your system. I checked both files and cannot reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @Deckard Sorry... What "BS" means? Well, may be really a problem on my System, but, this same behaviour happens on my IE9 at work. And recently I discovered another problem, more serious, some questions are not completed on my Surveys. I tried complet a survey with my IE9 and the data was not saved!! So... May be a SERVER problem?